# Problema con Eclipse Neon

Tags: java, eclipse

Tengo un script para preguntarme palabras a mi mismo. Le doy al botón Design en Eclipse y me pasa esto-https://gyazo.com/87b52a139102fb6592a232d332cfd33b.

Show Stack Trace:
https://gyazo.com/d420187a6e24a7e1ee4172f27bd0eb6d https://gyazo.com/cb8c305b70734648271f78d3b3e3c412 
https://gyazo.com/2278e4af4947afd99aa898f4ab69fdcb
https://gyazo.com/bc421fb9d593b62b3568135746489753
https://gyazo.com/41ade92b8bc89d13cad174ff925b010e

Este es el script:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class WoordjesLeren {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner wordL= new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner wordR = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner answer= new Scanner(System.in);


        System.out.println("Word:");    
        String wordL1= wordL.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Translation:"); 

        String wordR1= wordR.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Word:");    
        String wordL2= wordL.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Translation:"); 

        String wordR2= wordR.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Word:");    
        String wordL3= wordL.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Translation:"); 

        String wordR3= wordR.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Word:");    
        String wordL4= wordL.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Translation:"); 

        String wordR4= wordR.nextLine();

        System.out.println(wordL2 + " -> ");

        String answer2= answer.nextLine();
        if (answer2.equals(wordR2)){
            System.out.println("Your answer is correct.");

        }else{
            System.out.println("Your answer is incorrect.");
        }
        System.out.println(wordL3 + " -> ");

        String answer3= answer.nextLine();
        if (answer3.equals(wordR3)){
            System.out.println("Your answer is correct.");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Your answer is incorrect.");
        }
        System.out.println(wordL4 + " -> ");

        String answer4= answer.nextLine();
        if (answer4.equals(wordR4)){
            System.out.println("Your answer is correct.");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Your answer is incorrect.");
        }
        System.out.println(wordL1 + " -> ");

        String answer1= answer.nextLine();
        if (answer1.equals(wordR1)){
            System.out.println("Your answer is correct.");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Your answer is incorrect.");
        }

        System.out.println("This was the exam, well done.");
    }
}
```

Comment: En la parte de abajo del mensaje pone "Show Stack Trace" en azul. Deberías poder pulsarlo y deberían aparecer muchas lineas con información sobre el error. Podrías mostrarnos ese error? Sería más facil saber la causa (y por lo tanto, también la solución).

Comment: Ya he puesto el show stack trace

Comment: como norma general, no pongas imagenes para mostrar texto, copia y pega el texto de tus errores, stacktraces, logs y codigo para facilitar la lectura y posterior busqueda....

Comment: Me parece que el plugin no está instalado en Eclipse Neon o no funciona. Verifica que el plugin funciona correctamente.